# How to implement this jquery example correctly. Show/Hide Div on Hover, navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I'm trying to implement the instructions from this answered question [Jquery show div on hover then when user hovers out of div hide it help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018327/jquery-show-div-on-hover-then-when-user-hovers-out-of-div-hide-it-help) and then add a bit more functionality. Here is what I combined the question and answer code into:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//when user hovers over plans the mainnavbottom is shown
    $(".plans").hover(
    $('.mainnavbottom').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event) {
        switch(event.type) {
            case 'mouseenter':
               // when user enters the div
               $(".mainnavbottom").show("fast");
            break;
            case 'mouseleave':
              // leaves
              $(".mainnavbottom").hide("slow");
            break;
        }
    });

 });
```

I can't get it to work. I'm sure it's because I am a javascript n00b so any suggestions would be appreciated.

I've also tried [jQuery hoverIntent Plugin show / hide div on parent hover, but keep showing when hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485669/jquery-hoverintent-plugin-show-hide-div-on-parent-hover-but-keep-showing-when) but again no joy.

Perhaps I'm adding the answer code incorrectly to the head? Taking the two examples I cited can anyone show me the full javascript code for the head? I feel like I am making a simple mistake here.

Assuming I can get that to work I would like to add one other dimension to it. Once the div from the above code "appears" it contains several more links, the user can then hover each of those "buttons" and see more info (text and possibly image). I would like that text & image to be a clickable part of the link if possible, but could probably live without it.

It may be that once I get the above code working I can just apply the same concepts to the secondary hover, but I'm not sure since I've been unsuccessful with the above code. Can anyone spot my (probably obvious) error? And does the added functionality I mentioned sound like it will be a problem.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

**Edit - Someone asked for me to post all code**

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//when user hovers over plans the mainnavbottom is shown
    $("#plans").hover(
    $('#mainnavbottom').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event) {
        switch(event.type) {
            case 'mouseenter':
               // when user enters the div
               $("#mainnavbottom").show("fast");
            break;
            case 'mouseleave':
              // leaves
              $("#mainnavbottom").hide("slow");
            break;
        }
    });

 });
</script>
</head>

<body>
       <div id="plans"> // some stuff </div>
       <div id="mainnavbottom"> 
          // some other stuff that I want to 
          // keep showing if users hover over it 
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, done. Changed from class to id based on comments below.

Comment: Could you post CSS too? or is there any?

Comment: No CSS yet, I was more concerned with whether or not I could get functionality I wanted before styling it.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience jquery isn't good about working with object classes. I'd try changing all the `(".mainnavbottom")` to `("#mainnavbottom")` and making sure the div in question has `id="mainnavbottom"`.

EDIT: Same thing goes for `(".plans")`

Comment: How would that help? jQuery is perfectly capable of selecting elements by class name.

Comment: Valid HTML should have only one of each ID; if he has multiple, he should use classes; otherwise, IDs are a better option.

Comment: this has nothing to do with it, jQuery is quite good at selecting by class, it's a core feature of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

See edit below:

Could be better written like this (excuse the formatting, I'm on my iTouch):

```
$(function(){
    $(".plans").hover(function(){
               $(".mainnavbottom").show("fast");
},function(){
              $(".mainnavbottom").hide("slow");
 });
});
```

|| EDIT ||

It's tricky to keep the mainnavbottom visible.  I personally would opt to use CSS styles and the :hover value instead of using jQuery.  However, I hope this works for you.  I had to set variables, and test whether the mouse was hovering over the plans or the mainnavbottom div.  I needed to use the .mouseleave() function on the mainnavbottom.  Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/jxPTM/) that I used, and below is the relevant code:

```
var nav = $('#mainnavbottom');
var plans = $('#plans');
    plans.mouseover(function(){     
        nav.show("fast");
    }).mouseout(function(){
        if(nav.is(':hover')){
            nav.mouseleave(function(){
                if(plans.is(':hover')){
                    return;
                        }else{
                                     nav.hide('slow');
                        }
            });
        }else{
         nav.hide('slow');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. This functions but you can't hover over the div once it appears (it just disappears), which is what I need.

Comment: Perhaps you could put .stop().delay(3000) before the hide function.

Comment: Or better yet, add .mainnavbottom to the event handler.  I'll update in a sec.

Comment: actually I would add the condition if(nav.is(':not(":animated")')) to the .show() animation, to prevent queueing.

Comment: And slideUp() and slideDown() are much nicer animations, I find.

Comment: Thank you, the fiddle looks good. I'm away but will test later today. Also, my brain was so focused on javascript to do this I didn't even consider CSS. Thanks, will think about that too.

Comment: I think this would be perfect solution for me except on IE it does not fade out on mouse out. Sigh, always IE...

Answer (score 0):

**Your braces are screwed something awful.**

.mouseenter & mouseleave is not needed, as `.hover()` does this for you.

This is what I came up with (for some reason it doesn't like being in doc.ready, but I have limited time to look into that)

(FYI, the way your code (and my suggested fix) is written, "#mainnavbottom" won't be hidden originally.  It only gets hidden after you hover over it for the first time - but I digress..)

```
$("#plans").hover(
    function() {
        $("#mainnavbottom").show("fast");
    },
    function() {
       $("#mainnavbottom").hide("slow");
    }
);
```

Here's a fiddle for that.

http://jsfiddle.net/KevinGabbert/pcJt8/

---

If, however, you *still* wanted those events, the braces in your example were still messed up, and this is my best attempt at what you were trying to do. (basically, I made what you did legal. I know that sometimes I need a visualization, so I'll go there.)

but again, this is not good code as it likely has some wicked event craziness going on..

**(don't try this at home)**

```
 $("#plans").hover(
        function() {
            alert("hover");

            $('#mainnavbottom').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
                //yada yada

            });
        },
        function() {
            alert("unhover");

            $('#mainnavbottom').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
                 //yada yada
            }); 
        }
    );
```

---

also, elaborating on what Artur said above:  the reason you want to use the id "#plans" instead of the class ".plans" is because there is only 1 id on a page.  JQuery's traversal will stop after finding it.

When using the class selector ".plans", it traverses the *entire page* looking for ALL elements of that class, which can confuse things if you have a large or complicated page, and make debugging harder.

Comment: Thanks, I like the fiddle (which is wicked cool btw, didn't know about it) but unfortunately I need to then hover over the appeared div. I'm going to go through the suggestions people have made later today so it may be problem solved. Will post back once I review everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#plans").hover(
      function() {
        $("#mainnavbottom").show("fast");               
        $('#mainnavbottom').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event) {
          switch(event.type) {
            case 'mouseenter':
              // when user enters the div
              $("#mainnavbottom").show("fast");
            break;
           case 'mouseleave':
             // leaves
             $("#mainnavbottom").hide("slow");
           break;
          }
        });
      },
      function() {
        $("#mainnavbottom").hide("slow");               
        $('#mainnavbottom).bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(event) {
          switch(event.type) {
            case 'mouseenter':
              $("#mainnavbottom").show("fast");
            break;
            case 'mouseleave':
              $("#mainnavbottom").hide("slow");
            break;
          }
         }); 
       }
     );
```

Comment: It's customary to add some explanation of your code, how it works, or how it is different from the OP's code or other answers.